# Laravel 5 how to convert AJAX response JSON into PHP, so I can loop through it with foreach on the view?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

I'm working on an AJAX search function for my `users` table, and I've managed to get until I get back the content of the response JSON file. But I can't figure out how could I hand it's content over to the `$users` PHP array, so I could loop through it.

The JS:

```
$('.searchbar').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/results',
            data: {keyword: $('.searchbar').value()},
            success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(){
                    console.log("No results for " + data + ".");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The route: `Route::get('results', 'SearchesController@search');`

The search function in `SearchesController`:

```
public function search(Request $request) {

    $keyword = $request->get('keyword');

    $users = \App\User::where("username", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("firstname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("lastname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("phone", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")->get();

    return \Response::json($users);

}
```

The view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
      <td class='text-center'>{{$user->username}}</td>
      <td class='text-center'>{{$user->firstname}}</td>
      <td class='text-center'>{{$user->lastname}}</td>
      <td class='text-center'>{{$user->email}}</td>
      <td class='text-center'>{{$user->phone}}</td>
      <td class='text-center'>{!! link_to_action('UsersController@edit', 'Edit', $user->id, ['class'=>'btn btn-warning', 'style'=>'margin-bottom:5px']); !!}
        {!! Form::open(['action' => ['UsersController@destroy', $user->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

So shortly, the content of `\Response::json($users);` should end up on the view as `$users`. Or should I change my whole approach and find a solution to `console.log` everything with JS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use templating engine to create your table via js using - `underscore.js`

Comment: did you passed your array in to your view?

Comment: Actually that's exactly the question, "how?" :)

Comment: replace `return \Response::json($users);` with `return view('results', array(
     'users' => $users
    ));`

Comment: `return \Response::json($users)->with([
                    'view' => 'results',
                    'users' => '{$users}',
            ]);` Somehow like this, or where does the 2nd return come? And another thing, if I return a view, doesn't it reload??

Comment: that's not correct.
what you want to to show the loop data inside the view? not a json?

Comment: I'd like to loop the results out, to get the same view as posted above. Maybe it's not correct to use php for loop in this case, but then should I return the content of the table in js? Like the details of the found users are displayed in the same kinda table.

Comment: let's be clear what is really you wanted in your ajax response?
the table inside your results? or 
a json data?]

Comment: The table with my results. It's just my first ajax job and I didn't know whether I need a json response or not.

Comment: ah so you use `return view('results', array( 'users' => $users ));` this will passed your variable `users` and render your `results` view which display your table

Comment: Ohh man, thanks a lot!! I just thought, that in case if I return a view, then the page reloads which doesn't count as ajax. In which cases do you return a json by the way?

Comment: @sklrboy I posted it as my answer. if this help you just mark it check. thank you, anyway a json is a data which can be use by javascript . the best scenario to return a json object is when you are getting a pure value or json object in your ajax response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
return \Response::json($users);
```

to

```
return view('results', array( 'users' => $users ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Controller

```
 $users = \App\User::where("username", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("firstname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("lastname", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("phone", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")->get();

if($users)
    return response()->json(['users' => $users], 200);

return response()->json(['msg' => 'No result found!'], 404);
```

> Ajax

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.users, function(i, user){
        //do something
        consloe.log(user.firstname);
    });
},
error: function(error){
    console.log(error.msg);
}
```

Comment: Still the same result, as it's not an answer I think to my question. I got the results back, that was not a problem. But how can I display them the same way in the table? Can I concert it into that PHP variable $users and the loop through it, or should I change to another method and use JS to display them?